# How to use Google Translator API in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-translator-toolkit

I want to know whether I can use Google Translator API in asp.net or not?
I am using .net framework 3.5 and add the Google Transaltor API .dll in bin folder. Code is here.

```
string Text = "This is a string to translate";
Google.API.Translate.TranslateClient tc = new TranslateClient("www.google.com");
string trans = tc.Translate(Text,"en","hi");
```

On debugging its throws the exception:

> [response status:403]Please use Translate v2. See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

What is the reason of this exception??